# Does anything like Selenium GRID for Nunit projects exist?

Tags: .net, nunit, distributed

It would be really nice to speed up testing to be able to run tests on multiple machines (this is actually Acceptance/Integration tests, not Unit tests...). Is there an existing easy way to do that using NUnit?

Answer (score 0):

@DotNetWise points out that [NUnitGridRunner](http://code.google.com/p/nunitgridrunner/) it is dead, and the author proposes alternatives:

> *Note: I've given up on this project as I've found that JetBrain's [Team City](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) provides a viable option. [Cruise](http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/cruise/1.1/help/welcome_to_cruise.html) also provides some grid processing but not as good.*

The Team City ["Build Grid" feature](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/build_grid.html) might be what you're looking for.

I think you *don't* want [PNUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=pnunit&r=2.5). While it stands for "Parallel NUnit," its home page says:

> PNUnit is not intended for "casual" parallelism merely to make the tests run faster. Rather, it's intended as a way to test applications composed of distributed, communicating components.

Comment: NUnitGridRunner is dead from 2009